# VB.Net 3 different characters

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I was given a task to make a casino slot machine using the built-in random numbers functions. The idea is that it is supposed to be 3 slots each with random numbers that trigger 1 out of 4 different characters.

```
Dim slot1, slot2, slot3, loops As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start!")
    Console.ReadKey()
    Do
        Randomize()
        slot1 = Math.Floor(Rnd() * 4) + 1
        slot2 = Math.Floor(Rnd() * 4) + 1
        slot3 = Math.Floor(Rnd() * 4) + 1
        If slot1 = 1 Or slot2 = 1 Or slot3 = 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine(Chr(3))
        ElseIf slot1 = 2 Or slot2 = 2 Or slot3 = 2 Then
            Console.WriteLine(Chr(4))
        ElseIf slot1 = 3 Or slot2 = 3 Or slot3 = 3 Then
            Console.WriteLine(Chr(5))
        ElseIf slot1 = 4 Or slot2 = 4 Or slot3 = 4 Then
            Console.WriteLine(Chr(6))
        End If
        loops = loops + 1
    Loop Until loops > 3
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", slot1)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("{0}     |     {1}", slot1, slot2, slot3)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("{0}     |     {1}     |     {2}", slot1, slot2, slot3)
```

My issue is that when the programs starts to run, it displays not enough characters for some reason and the places where the characters should be are only numbers, not the characters specified in the 'If' Statements

Comment: because you are printing integers.

Comment: What is the point of Chr(3) Chr(4) etc? Below 32 are invisible control characters, look at an ascii table.

Comment: turn on option strict and you will stop shooting yourself in the foot

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim r As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim n(2) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        n(i) = r.Next(0, 4)
    Next
    Label1.Text = String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", n(0), n(1), n(2))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Test your code as follows:

```
Dim slot1, slot2, slot3, loops As Integer
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start!")
Console.ReadKey(True)   ' Is True for the pressed key is not displayed on the console
Console.WriteLine()
For i = 0 To 3         ' Instead of the [Do ... Loop] block 
    Randomize(Timer)   ' With timer is strongest.
    slot1 = Math.Floor(Rnd() * 4) + 3   ' +3 instead of [If ... End If] block
    slot2 = Math.Floor(Rnd() * 4) + 3
    slot3 = Math.Floor(Rnd() * 4) + 3
    Console.Write(Chr(slot1))
    Console.Write(Chr(slot2))
    Console.WriteLine(Chr(slot3))
Next
Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("{0}", Chr(slot1))
Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("{0}     |     {1}", Chr(slot1), Chr(slot2))
Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("{0}     |     {1}     |     {2}", Chr(slot1), Chr(slot2), Chr(slot3))
Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit!")
Console.ReadKey(True)
```